# Showing wrong name in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

My Macbook's name is 'Suman'[image]. But in terminal I have something different. How to solve it ?

Comment: The command to display your computer name within a `Terminal` window is `hostname`.
From your screen copy it is correct.

Comment: In the interest of having a good searchable question, let's leave the terminology here intact even though to people familiar with shell and host names, the title here is less precise than we might like.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you've changed it, the default Bash prompt is

```
computer-name:directory username$
```

Therefore it's correct.

---

```
Suman:~ beautifulmind$
```

…means your computer is called `Suman`, you're in your home folder `~` and your account is `beautifulmind`.

Comment: How to change the account ?

Comment: @Suman See [this Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1428?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

Comment: → Suman: this is a new question and you should avoid questions within comments. No one will be able to find the relevant answer to your new question by digging in every question comments.